# ListView and Drop Down Menu with Dividers

Tags: android, listview, android-menu

I have a custom listView of the users installed apps and I want to have a drop down menu with different options such as "alphabatize" or "create custom divider" and when that option is picked, it will rearrange the listView based on that choice via dividers. (For alphabatize it would show A-Z on the dividers and organize accordingly and so on.)

How can I create a dropdown menu that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Spinner for the drop down menu. Override the onItemSelected() for the spinner.

```
spinnerSelectDivider.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        if(position == 0)
        {   
            customListView.setDivider(someDrawableAZ);
        }
        else if(position == 1)
        {
            customListView.setDivider(someDrawableCustom);
        }
    }
}
```

For reference on setDivider method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)